# Functions inside functions, contexts and register_shutdown_function

Tags: php, function, variables, scope, nested

I have this code (Is more complex, but I limited it to some lines).

```
function callfunction($data = "") {
    $isdata = true; // Data already set Flag
    if ($data == "") {
        $isdata = false;
        $data = randomLettersString(10);
    }
    if ($isdata) { // If data was set, environment files are needed.
        /*
            ... Prepare environment files
        */
        function cleanup() {
            global $data;
            /*
                ... test $data and cleanup environment files.
            */
        }
        register_shutdown_function('cleanup'); // Force cleanup
    }
    $ret = shell_exec(/* script that has chances of hanging */);
    if($isdata) { // If data was set, environment is cleaned.
        cleanup();
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

As you can see, I have a function that is called somewhere else in my code, and that function can have some `$data`. If the function is called with some `$data`, that means that, before calling the `shell_exec` script, the environment has to be prepared (some database calls, some files creation and such things).

The script is an script that calls some external APIs, so there's a chance that the script hangs or whatever (very rarely will happen, but as long as I don't have the control of those APIs, at least I want to have the control if the script times out for whatever reason).

Now, I'm not sure how can I access `$data` from the nested function. I have `global $data;` but I'm not sure, since `$data` is not a global variable but local variable inside the function.

Also, if the script does not hang and `cleanup()` is called after it, I supose that altough `cleanup()` is declared inside an `if` condition, it persists until the function ends so I can call it in another `if` condition, that's how PHP works, right?

And now the thing that scares me. If PHP works in a manner where every variable will last until the function ends, then if the code times out and PHP calls register_shutdown_function('cleanup'), then the nested `cleanup()` function will be called inside the context of the main `callfunction()` function, right? so, `global $data` will point to the data inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not have a concept of "nested functions".

```
function foo() {
    function bar() {}
}

bar(); // error, bar not declared
foo();
bar(); // success!
```

This does not in any way mean that the functions are nested or that their scope is shared. Merely the **function declaration** of `bar` is nested inside `foo`. That means the function will not be *declared* until `foo` is executed. That's the same as this:

```
if (false) {
    function bar() {}
}

bar(); // error
```

Once you execute `foo`, the function `bar` will be declared. Globally. Should you ever try to run `foo` again, PHP will try to redeclare `bar` and fail with an error.

I hope this explains the basic concept. That also means there's no special affordances for scope; `bar` does not have any more access to `foo`'s scope than if you'd write its declaration outside of `foo`.

The exception here are *anonymous functions*:

```
function foo() {
    $data = ..;
    $bar = function () use ($data) {}
}
```

You can extend scope of selected variables into anonymous functions using `use`. This function is now truly scoped to within `foo` and can also be declared as many times as you want.

Having said all this, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do there, but this hopefully helps already.

Comment: Very detailed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

PHP scopes are a little more tricky. Try this:

```
// define the $data var outside ('globally')
// if this is a class you could do 
// public static $data; and access it static::$data from within its class
// or ClassName::$data from outside its class
var $data;

// then define the cleanup function outside
function cleanup(){
    global $data;
}

// or if you are in a class
public function cleanup(){
    // handle $data
    var_dump(static::$data);
}

function callfunction($data = "") {
    $isdata = true; // Data already set Flag
    if ($data == "") {
        $isdata = false;
        $data = randomLettersString(10);
    }
    // if in class, we would need to push $data into the static var
    //static::$data = $data;
    if ($isdata) { // If data was set, environment files are needed.
        /*
            ... Prepare environment files
        */
        register_shutdown_function('cleanup'); // Force cleanup
        // or if in a class
        // register_shutdown_function(array('ClassName', 'cleanup'));
    }
    $ret = shell_exec(/* script that has chances of hanging */);
    if($isdata) { // If data was set, environment is cleaned.
        cleanup();
        // or if in a class
        // static::cleanup();
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

There is another approach (I'm not able to test it at the moment) it depends on PHP 5.3+, it makes use of PHP's closures. **Note**: This could also require pulling the `cleanup` function outside of the `callfunction`.

```
function callfunction($data = "") {
    $isdata = true; // Data already set Flag
    if ($data == "") {
        $isdata = false;
        $data = randomLettersString(10);
    }
    if ($isdata) { // If data was set, environment files are needed.
        /*
            ... Prepare environment files
        */
        function cleanup($data) {
            // no need for globals here, hooray!
            /*
                ... test $data and cleanup environment files.
            */
        }
        // set the callback as a PHP closure and allow it to use the $data var
        register_shutdown_function(function() use ($data){
             cleanup($data);
        }); // Force cleanup
    }
    $ret = shell_exec(/* script that has chances of hanging */);
    if($isdata) { // If data was set, environment is cleaned.
        cleanup($data);
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Let us know which approach works so that I can update the answer accordingly!

Comment: I accept the other answer because explains with lot of details how PHP scopes works, and that helped me a lot, but I upvote your answer because I was thinking if I can use anonymous `function() use` inside `register_shutdown_function` and you just told me to do so. Thank you for your reply. I'll update when I test it. Have some lines to recode.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! glad to hear that